# Calculate the difference between groups in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is my table

```
Machine   Date        Hours    Interp
A         12/12/2019   250      AR
B         12/12/2019   186      NAR
C         12/13/2019   77       NAR
A         12/19/2019   277      MC
B         12/20/2019   195      NAR
A         12/30/2019   300      NAR
```

What I need to do is calculate the difference in hours between oil samples by Machine. So I want to add a column.

```
Machine   Date        Hours    Interp  Difference
A         12/12/2019   250      AR     0
B         12/12/2019   186      NAR    0
C         12/13/2019   77       NAR    0
A         12/19/2019   277      MC     22
B         12/20/2019   195      NAR    9
A         12/30/2019   300      NAR    23
```

I know I need to use EARLIER but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, `EARLIER` is not what you want. It has nothing to do with dates. You want to find the last date (`MAX` or `LASTDATE`) prior to the current one (for each machine).

Comment: Do I not need to use the EARLIER function to make sure the comparison is made with the same machine?

Comment: If you're writing a calculated column, yes, that is a way to reference that row context.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. But I cant get the syntax right. 
```DAX
Difference = [Hours] - Calculate(Max([Hours], EARLIER([Machine])) 
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
Difference =
VAR PrevDate =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Table[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[Machine] ),
        Table[Date] < EARLIER ( Table[Date] )
    )
VAR PrevHours =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table[Hours] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[Machine] ),
        Table[Date] = PrevDate
    )
RETURN
    Table[Hours] - PrevHours
```

This uses `ALLEXCEPT` to remove all the row context except for the `Machine` name.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you